# Close menu bar menu with applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, automation

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    tell (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 where description is "system sound volume")
        click
    end tell
end tell
```

will open the sound menu bar item, but I want to delay one second then close it.

I tried:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    tell (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 where description is "system sound volume")
        click
        delay 1
        cancel
    end tell
end tell
```

but that didn't work

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it.  This works for me.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    tell (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 where description is "system sound volume")
        click
        delay 1
        key code 53
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: But if the user selects another app then the escape will be sent to the focussed app.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about that because your script draws focus to the system and sound volume icon, then clicks.  With A delay of only one second, I doubt there would be anytime to draw focus to another application before the escape event.

Comment: No I am sure about this, because I have tested. About 5 hours ago